# Can we make the font size configurable in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have developed a WPF client which poupaltes some sample data into it from the database.I have two labels and two textboxes corresspondingly where the data is filled into the textboxes.I have made the setup file and deployed it on my desktop.

While i start my client i see that the font size is smaller.So i don't want to go back and change the code and deploy it again.Is there a way where i can make this fontsize configurableon the app.config file of the client ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231631/how-to-enable-users-to-edit-a-control-style-in-runtime/) should put you in the right path.

It uses bound values from an application's `Settings.settings` file to control the applications styles.